# Android Compose App Crashes during UI Testing (Instrumented Tests)

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following Android Studio's Documentation for learning Kotlin and Jetpacks Compose. For Unit 2, Pathway 3, we are supposed to practice writing both local tests and instrumented tests for the Tip Calculator App that was developed.

When I manually tested the App, it works but it fails the Instrumented Test as the entire app closes during UI Testing. As a result, I encounter an Assertion Error,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (Text + EditableText contains 'Tip Amount: $2.00' (ignoreCase: false))

at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchOneOrDie(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:162)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertExists(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:137)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertExists$default(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:136)
at com.example.tipcalculator.TipCalculatorInstrumentedTestUI.calculate_20_percent_tip(TipCalculatorInstrumentedTestUI.kt:46)
```

Does anyone know why this maybe happening? I have attached both my Tip Calculator App Code and Instrumented Tests codes below:

1. Instrumented Tests

```
package com.example.tipcalculator

import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithTag
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithText
import androidx.compose.ui.test.performTextInput
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import com.example.tipcalculator.ui.theme.TipCalculatorTheme

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TipCalculatorInstrumentedTestUI {
    @get: Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    // Compiler knows @Test in androidTest refers to Instrumented Tests, while in Test Directory refers to Local Tests
    @Test
    fun calculate_20_percent_tip() {
        // Set the UI Content, Code looks similar to Main Activity SetContent where we render the Screen and App
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            TipCalculatorTheme {
                TipCalculatorScreen()
            }
        }

        // Accessing the UI Component as a Node to access its particular text with onNodeWithText() method to access TextField Composable
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Bill Amount")
            .performTextInput("10")     // Pass in the Value of the Text that we wants to populate it with

        // Apply Same Approach for Tip Percentage
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tip (%)")
            .performTextInput("20")

        // Use Assertion to ensure that the Text Composable reflects the accurate Tip to be given
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tip Amount: $2.00").assertExists()
    }
}
```

2. Application Code

```
package com.example.tipcalculator

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFocusManager
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.tipcalculator.ui.theme.TipCalculatorTheme
import java.text.NumberFormat
import kotlin.math.round

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TipCalculatorTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    TipCalculatorScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TipCalculatorScreen() {
    // Mutable State that receives 0 as a parameter wrapped in a State Object, making its value observable
    var amountInput by remember {
        // Importing remember setter and getter functions allows us to read and set amountInput
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    // Mutable State for Tip
    var tipInput by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    // Variable to remember State of the Switch
    var roundUp by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    // Interface to Control Focus in Compose
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    // Convert to Double or a Null. If Null, return 0 after the Elvis Operator
    val amount = amountInput.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    val tipPercentage = tipInput.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    
    // Calculate Tip
    val tip = CalculateTip(amount = amount, tipPercent = tipPercentage, roundUp = roundUp)

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(32.dp)
    ) {
        // Screen Title
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.calculate_tip),
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        // Text Field for User
        // Pass the Hoisted State back into the Child Function
        EditNumberField(
            value = amountInput,
            onValueChange = { amountInput = it },
            label = R.string.bill_amount,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                // Move Focus downwards to the next composable when the Next Button is clicked
                onNext = {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                }
            )
        )

        // Input Field for Tip Percentage
        EditNumberField(
            label = R.string.how_was_the_service,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                // Closes the Keyboard when Done is pressed
                onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
            ),
            value = tipInput,
            onValueChange = { tipInput = it }
        )

        // Rounding Function
        RoundTipRow(
            // Setting Initial State
            roundUp = roundUp,
            // Updating the State when the Switch is clicked
            onRoundUpChanged = { roundUp = it }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))

        // Display the Tip Amount to be given
        Text(
            // Can use tip to sub into placeholder as the String has a %s placeholder
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.tip_amount, tip),
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }

}

@Composable
fun EditNumberField(
    // Hoist the State by introducing 2 Parameters
    @StringRes label: Int,      // To indicate that it is meant to be a String Resource
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions,
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,     // Takes a string as input but has no output
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,     // Set to Empty String; Since TextBox that displays the Value
        onValueChange = onValueChange, // Set to Empty Lambda Function; Callback that is triggered when User enters text
        label = { Text(text = stringResource(label))}, // Using Label instead of Hardcoding
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        singleLine = true,       // Ensures text box is a single horizontal textbox that is scrollable
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions, // Changing the look of the keyboard
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions   // Functionality for the Action Buttons i.e. Next/Done
    )
}

// Rounding Tip Switch Function
@Composable
private fun RoundTipRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    // Allowing us to hoist the state of the switch
    roundUp: Boolean,
    onRoundUpChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .size(48.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        // Text for Rounding Tip
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.round_up_tip))
        
        Switch(
            // Determines whether the Switch is Checked, i.e. the Current State
            checked = roundUp,
            // Callback called when the Switch is clicked
            onCheckedChange = onRoundUpChanged,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.End),
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                // Bad Practice since we are hardcoding the color and will be affected if Dark Mode is implemented for example
                uncheckedThumbColor = Color.DarkGray
            )
        )

    }
    
}

// Calculate Tip; Cannot be Private or the Local Tests will not have access to them
@VisibleForTesting      // Makes the Function Public but only for Testing purposes
internal fun CalculateTip(
    amount: Double,
    tipPercent: Double = 15.0,
    roundUp: Boolean
): String {
    var tip = tipPercent / 100 * amount

    if (roundUp == true) {
        // Rounding Up
        tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
    }
    // After calculating the tip, format and display the tip with the Number Class
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TipCalculatorTheme {
        TipCalculatorScreen()
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same course and my code crashed at the same point with a similar error:

java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (Text + EditableText contains 'Tip Amount: $2.00' (ignoreCase: false))

I tracked it down to having a mismatch with the text value in the test and the text value on the UI. This is your test code:

```
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Bill Amount")
        .performTextInput("10")   
  
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tip (%)")
        .performTextInput("20")
   
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tip Amount: $2.00").assertExists()
```

Check that the text values "Bill Amount", "Tip (%)" and "Tip Amount: $2.00" exactly match the same values on the UI. In this case, if the UI shows "Tip amount: $2.00" but the test text value is "Tip Amount: $2.00", the test will fail. Your original error message shows that ignoreCase is false.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `TextField` for the bill amount and the tip are empty in the composable declaration.
If for instance the `TextField` for the bill was initialized with '0' in the UI, then when `composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Bill Amount").performTextInput("10")` is executed, the `TextField` will actually be 100.